# How is the `*var-name*` naming-convention used in clojure?

Tags: naming-conventions, lisp, clojure

As a non-lisper coming to clojure how should I best understand the naming convention where vars get a name like `*var-name*`?

This appears to be a lisp convention indicating a global variable. But in clojure such vars appear in namespaces as far as I can tell.

I would really appreciate a brief explanation of what I should expect when an author has used such vars in their code, ideally with a example of how and why such a var would be used and changed in a clojure library.

Comment: See: http://www.wisdomandwonder.com/link/952/lisp-style-rules

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a convention used in other Lisps, such as Common Lisp, to distinguish between [*special variables*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#special_variable), as distinct from *lexical variables*. A *special* or *dynamic* variable has its binding stored in a dynamic environment, meaning that its current value as visible to any point in the code depends upon how it may have been bound higher up the call stack, as opposed to being dependent only on the most local lexical binding form (such as `let` or `defn`).

Note that in his book [*Let Over Lambda*](http://letoverlambda.com/), Doug Hoyte argues against the "earmuffs" asterix convention for naming special variables. He uses an unusual macro style that makes reference to free variables, and he prefers not to commit to or distinguish whether those symbols will eventually refer to lexical or dynamic variables.

Though targeted specifically at Common Lisp, you might enjoy [Ron Garret](http://www.flownet.com/ron/)'s essay [*The Idiot's Guide to Special Variables*](http://www.flownet.com/ron/specials.pdf). Much of it can still apply to Clojure.

Comment: For others like me, who are grappling with new concepts using clojure as a first lisp a reference detailing more of how clojure handles binding is useful for comparison.  I found this blog http://clivetong.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!3F21DF299C355E7F!311.entry helpful.

Answer (score 18):

Functional programming is all about **safe predictable functions**. Infact some of us are afraid of that spooky "**action at a distance**" thing. When people call a function they get a warm fuzzy satisfaction that the function will always give them the same result if they call the function or read the value again. the `*un-warm-and-fuzzy*` bristly things exist to warn programmers that this variable is **less cuddly** than some of the others.

Answer (score 7):

Some references I found in the Clojure newsgroups:

> Re: making code readable
>   John D. Hume
>   Tue, 30 Dec 2008 08:30:57 -0800
>
> On Mon, Dec 29, 2008 at 4:10 PM, Chouser  wrote:
>   I believe the idiom for global values like this is to place asterisks
>   around the name.
>
> I thought the asterisk convention was for variables intended for
>   dynamic binding. It took me a minute to figure out where I got that
>   idea. "Programming Clojure" suggests it (without quite saying it) in
>   chapter 6, section 3.
>
> > "Vars intended for dynamic binding are sometimes called special vari-
> >     ables. It is good style to name them
> >     with leading and trailing asterisks."
>
> Obviously the book's a work in progress, but that does sound
>   reasonable. A special convention for variables whose values change (or
>   that my code's welcome to rebind) seems more useful to me than one for
>   "globals" (though I'm not sure I'd consider something like grid-size
>   for a given application a global). Based on ants.clj it appears Rich
>   doesn't feel there needs to be a special naming convention for that
>   sort of value.

and...

> I believe the idiom for global values like this is to place asterisks
>   around the name.  Underscores (and CamelCase) should only be used when
>   required for Java interop:

```
(def *grid-size* 10)
(def *height* 600)
(def *margin* 50)
(def *x-index* 0)
(def *y-index* 1)
```

Comment: Is markdown breaking your code example? I assume the stuff that is italicized should be in asterisks such as `*grid-size*`? (I escaped the `*` by putting them in backticks.)

Comment: Definitely, and thanks for pointing it out! Let me see if I can get that fixed...

Comment: First off, you'll see the term _earmuffs_ ... a humorous reference to the asterisks on either side.

In more recent releases of Clojure (starting in 1.3, I believe) only vars marked with the `:dynamic` meta data could be dynamic (that is, bound to a per-thread value). You get a warning if you name a var with earmuffs but don't also mark it as dynamic.