# When to use `constantly` in clojure, how and when are its arguments evaluated?

Tags: clojure, evaluation

In the accepted answer to another question, [Setting Clojure "constants" at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997910/setting-clojure-constants-at-runtime) the clojure function `constantly` is used.

The definition of `constantly` looks like so:

```
(defn constantly
  "Returns a function that takes any number of arguments and returns x."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [x] (fn [& args] x))
```

The doc string says what it does but not why one would use it.

In the answer given in the previous question constantly is used as follows:

```
(declare version)

(defn -main
  [& args]
 (alter-var-root #'version (constantly (-> ...)))
 (do-stuff))
```

So the function returned by constantly is directly evaluated for its result. I am confused as to how this is useful. I am probably not understanding how `x` would be evaluated with and without being wrapped in `constantly'.

When should I use `constantly` and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `constantly` function is useful when an API expects a function and you just want a constant. This is the case in the example provided in the question.

Most of the `alter-*` functions (including `alter-var-root`) take a function, to allow the caller to modify something based on its old value. Even if you just want the new value to be 7 (disregarding the old value), you still need to provide a function (providing just 7 will result in  an attempt to evaluate it, which will fail). So you have to provide a function that just returns 7. `(constantly 7)` produces just this function, sparing the effort required to define it.

Edit: As to second part of the question, `constantly` is an ordinary function, so its argument is evaluated before the constant function is constructed. So `(constantly @myref)` always returns the value referenced by `myref` at the time `constantly` was called, even if it is changed later.